# Lock Adding into a collection

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, locking, task-parallel-library

My first thought was regarding `SpinLock` or `Concurrent Collections`
Lock Will work here as I tested, but it's more expensive !

The Process here is based on Parallel Programming. And the task is running more than one in parallel.

During the SpinLock Version I encounter an error some times randomly saying similar to `"Index out of range"`.

The SpinLock version which I wrote can't do the job I wanted, Could any change be made on it to make it work ? or Isn't it built for exactly related to this case ?

Any Info ?

Does it have any better alternative ?

This is what I did :

```
     lock (lckRelatz)
     {
         relatz.Add(st);
     }
```

**And here is the SpinLock version - This is inside a method which is running in parallel :**

```
        SpinLock spinLk = new SpinLock();
        bool gotLock = false;
        try
        {
            spinLk.Enter(ref gotLock);
            relatz.Add(st);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (gotLock)
                spinLk.Exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are creating new `SpinLock` for each thread. That will not actually lock anything. You need to have one `SpinLock` and use that from all of your threads.

But using a concurrent collection is even better solution. They are highly optimized and using them means you don't have to worry about all the locking yourself.

Comment: Nice answer, seems you got the key, Which collection will work here ? BlockingCollection ? About the creation of the Lock I think, did it in several different ways in edits of my code and I think did add like what you said earlier but changed by time and didn't know the exact problem.

Comment: That depends on what exactly do you want, but `BlockingCollection` or `ConcurrentQueue` are the most useful. If you don't need blocking, `ConcurrentQueue` should be enough.